# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) CS50 Lab 2

Tags: c, cs50

Okay so im trying to create a scrabble game and made a funtion to compute score of user prompted word but no matter what im getting this error.

```
int compute_score(string word)
{
    int upletters[32];
    int letters[32];
    int n = 0;
    int s = 0;
    int z = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int sum = 0;
      for (int i = 65; i < 90;i++)
        {
           upletters[n]=i;
           n++;
        }
      for (int j = 97;j<122;j++)
        {
           letters[s]=j;
           s++;
        }
      for (int k = 0;k < strlen(word);k++)
       {
         if (isupper(word[k]))
          {
             do
              {
                z++;
              }
             while(word[k] != upletters[z]);
             sum +=upletters[z];
          }
         else if (islower(word[k]))
          {
             do
             {
               y++;
             }
             while(word[k] != letters[y]);
             sum +=letters[y];
          }
         else
          {
             sum += 0;
          }
        }
 return sum;
}
```

I tried almost everything but i don't even know whats the problem it even compiles without any error.

Comment: What does that do-while loop             do
              {
                z++;
              }
             while(word[k] != upletters[z]); mean?!

Comment: @nicefaa6taa, `upletters[z]` eventually access  `upletters[]` out of bounds.  Did you want `z` to be set to 0 before each `do` loop?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  I think i tried to find a char in wordk that is equal to upletter z then add that char upletter z to sum but this code is completely messed up and useless.I rewrote the whole thing and it worked flawlessy.That was just a newbie mistake sorry for your time

Comment: "I tried almost everything" Try single-stepping through the code with a debugger. Any decent beginner class teaches the basics of debugging early on.